# Is output compare timer or overflow timer more efficient

Tags: c, timer, arduino, microcontroller

I am using an arduino leonardo (ATmega32u4) to check if the value of a (analog) pressure sensor is above a certain threshold. I am using timer4 of the ATmega32u4 and mad a overflow timer as well as an output compare timer. The functionality and efficiency of both timers seem to be the same but I suppose one of them should be better. Does anyone know which one should be more efficient in this case?

```
Below the timer functions.

void setupOvfTimer4() {

    //clear timer4 registers
    OCR4C = 0;

    TCCR4A = 0;
    TCCR4B = 0;
    TCCR4C = 0;
    TCCR4D = 0;
    TCCR4E = 0;

    TCNT4 = 0; //clear timer4 count register
    TIMSK4 |= (1<<TOIE4);
    TCCR4B |= (1 << CS42 ) | (1<<CS41) | (1<<CS40); //sets prescaler to 64
    OCR4C = 249; //with prescaler /64 and 16 MHz clock this triggers every ms. (this is TOP).

}

void setupOcrTimer4() {
    TCCR4A = 0;                                      //Clear timer 4 register A
    TCCR4B = 0;                                      //Clear timer 4 register B
    TCNT4 = 0;                                       //Clear timer 4 counter register
    OCR4A = 249;                                     //Set timer 4 output register A to timer4Frequency (Hz)
    TCCR4B |= (1 << CS41);                           //Set timer 4 to compare mode (CTC)
    TCCR4B |= (1 << CS40);
    TCCR4B |= (1 << CS42);                           //Set no prescaler (16E6MHz / 1000Hz = 16e3 < 65535)    
    TIMSK4 |= (1 << OCIE4A);                         //Enable ISR immediately
}
```

Comment: Why do you have any reason to think that one is intrinsically better than the other? One requires less configuration and allows for continuous counting. The other allows you to be specific with the time period.

Comment: These functions are performed in hardware, so the cpu is not used in both cases. Hence, there is no performance difference for the running program

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? You can optimize the electrical power, code size, maintainability of the source code, or the hardware you need, or ... By the way, please do not comment on the obvious - it's going to be wrong earlier than you might expect. Write self-explanatory source code instead.